# Infinite limits on integration: acceptable notation

Tags: notation, limits, improper-integrals

So you have an integral like

$$

\int_{-\infty}^\infty{ \frac{dx}{1+4 x^2} }

$$

Schaum's Calculus 5e recommends you write this as

$$
\lim_{a \to -\infty} \int_a^b{ \frac{dx}{1+4 x^2} } + \lim_{c \to \infty} \int_b^c{ \frac{dx}{1+4 x^2} }
$$

Where b is chosen as a point where f(x) is defined.

Choosing b=0, you then get

$$
\lim_{a \to -\infty} \frac{1}{4} \int_a^0{ \frac{dx}{\frac{1}{4}+x^2} } + \lim_{c \to \infty} \frac{1}{4} \int_0^c{ \frac{dx}{\frac{1}{4}+x^2} }
$$

$$
\lim_{a \to -\infty} \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}{ 2x } |_a^0 + \lim_{c \to \infty} \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}{ 2x } |_0^c
$$

$$
0 - \lim_{a \to -\infty} \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}{ 2a } + \lim_{c \to \infty} \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}{ 2c } - 0
$$

$$
= \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Would it be correct to shortcut this as

1. Take the indefinite integral with no limits
   $$
   \frac{1}{4} \int{ \frac{dx}{ \frac{1}{4} + x^2} } = \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}{ 2x }
   $$
2. Evaluate
   $$
   = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{a \to -\infty} \lim_{b \to \infty} \tan^{-1}{ 2x } |_a^b
   $$

$$
= \frac{1}{2} \lim_{a \to -\infty} \lim_{b \to \infty} \left( \tan^{-1}{ 2b } - \tan^{-1}{ 2a } \right)
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2} \right) = \frac{ \pi }{2}
$$

So my question is surrounding limit notation and evaluation.  Is the above notation ok, or is it completely necessary to break it up into 2 limits?

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter because the integral exists in a fairly strong sense. In general you will have to be careful because I think the answer can depend on the value of $b$.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Hmmm... why? Replacing $b$ by $b'$ will add to the limit of the part from $a$ to $b$ the value of the integral from $b$ to $b'$ and will substract the same number from the limit of the integral from $b$ to $c$ so the results for $b$ and for $b'$ will coincide.

Comment: @Didier: I may be misremembering - in particular, I may be confusing this with taking the limits on the left and right simultaneously - but I think there may be issues if the integrand has multiple singularities on the real line.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I see. In the present case there are no singularities, nevertheless your point is one which is worth keeping in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see why they have this approach, try

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{ \frac{8x \;dx}{1+4 x^2} } $$

using the recommended method [the indefinite integral is $\log(1+4 x^2) + \text{constant}$], and then using your suggestion, and alternatively what would happen if you had to work out

$$\lim_{c \to +\infty} \int_{-c}^c { \frac{8x \;dx}{1+4 x^2} }.$$

You would be looking with the recommended method  at something like $\infty-\infty$, with your suggestion of doing the upper limit first at $\lim_{a \to -\infty} +\infty = +\infty$,  and with the alternative method at $\lim_{c \to +\infty} 0 = 0$.  In fact you want the alarm bells of the difference between two infinities.

Comment: The integral can be interpreted in the Cauchy sense, though.